# what is the best algorithm to solve 'toy matching puzzle'?

Tags: algorithm

Imagine puzzle like this :
[puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BntT0.jpg)

I have several shapes, for example :

- 10 circles
- 8 triangles
- 9 squares

I also have some plates to put shapes, for example :

- plate A : 2 circle holes, 3 triangle holes, 1 square holes
- plate B : 1 circle holes, 0 triangle hole, 3 square holes
- plate C : 2 circle holes, 2 triangle holes, 2 square holes

I want to find minimum numbers of plates to put shapes all (plates do not need to fill completely)

for example :

- I can pick 6 plates [A, A, A, B, B, C], and I can insert all shapes
- but I also can pick [A, A, C, C, C] and this is okay too,
- so answer of this problem is : 5

If this problem generalized to N-types of shapes, and M-types of plates,
What is the best algorithm to solve this problem and what is time complexity of the answer?

Comment: Have you seen the "change making" DP problem? Pretty sure you can apply something similar, but just add more dimensions to your DP matrix. Plates are like the denominations, and number of shapes is the number of dimensions.

Comment: You may try a *branch and bound* algorithm for this linear constrained optimisation problem

Comment: This is a straightforward linear programming problem with constraints.  Look up support modules for that field.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a NP-hard problem, it is easier to see it once you realize that there is a very simple [polynomial time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) from the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) to this problem.

What I would suggest is for you to use [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) techniques in order to solve it.

An ILP that solves your problem can be the following:

```
// Data
Shapes  // array of integers of size n, contains the number of each shape to fit
Plates  // 2D array of size n * m, Plates[i][j] represents the number of shape of type i
        // that fit on a plate of type j
// Decision variables
X       // array of integer of size m, will represent the number of plates of each type to use
// Constraints
For all j in 1 .. m, X[j] >= 0   // number of plates cannot be negative
For all i in 1 .. n, sum(j in 1..m) Plates[i][j] * X[j] >= Shapes[i] // all shapes must fit
Objective function:
minimize sum(j in 1..n) X[j]
```

Write the pseudo code in OPL, feed it to a [linear programming solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software), and you should get a solution reasonably fast, given the similarity of this problem with bin packing.

Edit: if you do not want to go though the trouble of learning LP basics, OPL, LP solvers, etc .... then the best and easiest approach for this problem would be a good old [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) implementation of this problem. Branch and bound is a very simple and powerful algorithm that can be used to solve a wide range of problem .... a must-know.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem should be done using dynamic programming I think.

Here is a solution in pseudo-code (I haven't tested it, but I think it should work):

```
parts = the number of shapes we want to fit as a vector
plates = the of plates we can use as a matrix (vector of vector)

function findSolution(parts, usedPlates):
    if parts < 0: //all elements < 0
        return usedPlates;
    else:
        bestSolution = null //or anything that shows that there is no solution yet
        for X in plates:
            if (parts > 0 on any index where X is > 0): //prevents an infinite loop (or stack overflow because of the recursion) that would occur using only e.g. the plate B from your question
                used = findParts(parts - X, used.add(X)); //elementwise subtraction; recursion
                if (used.length < best.length):
                    //the solution is better than the current best one
                    best = used;

        //return the best solution that was found
        return best
```

using the values from your question the initial variables would be:

```
parts = [10, 8, 9]
plates = [[2, 3, 1], [1, 0, 3], [2, 2, 2]]
```

and you would start the function like this:

```
solution = findSolution(parts /*= [10, 8, 9]*/, new empty list);
//solution would probably be [A, A, C, C, C], but also [C, C, C, C, C] would be possible (but in every case the solution has the optimal length of 5)
```

Using this algorithm you divide the problem in smaller problems using recursion (which is what most dynamic programming algorithms do).

The time complexity of this is not realy good, because you have to search every possible solution.
According to the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) the time complexity should be something like: O(n^(log_b(a))) where n = a = the number of plates used (in your example 3). b (the base of the logarithm) can't be calculated here (or at least I don't know how) but I assume it would be close to 1 which makes it a quite big exponent. But it also depends on the size of the entries in the parts vector and the entries in the plates vectores (less plates needed -> better time complexity, much plates needed -> bad time complexity).

So the time complexity is not very good. For bigger problems this will take very very long, but for small problems like in your question it should work.